# How to make UI changes on xcode appear directly?

Tags: ios, uilabel

So the problem I'm facing is that I am changing the location of the label according to its width. and It's not taking effect immediately.

```
[self setItToFront:self.label];
```

Method setItToFront:

```
-(void) setItToFront: (UILabel*) label
{
    int labelWidth = label.frame.size.width;
    label.frame = CGRectMake(-(labelWidth), label.frame.origin.y, labelWidth,label.frame.size.height);
}
```

Now when I call the below method on a press of a button

```
    NSLog(@"%f",self.label.frame.size.width);
```

It gives me the initial width. Not the new width after changing its text.

The thing am doing is that am reading an xml webpage and updating the label's text with the webpage values. and am calling this method at the end to display the label with the new text at a certain location.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved [self.label sizeToFit] before the method call

```
    NSLog(@"%f",self.label.frame.size.width);
```

and that was it :) It was really silly !